# UIView subview being placed in unexpected position (Swift 4)

Tags: swift, uiview, coordinates, frame, cashapelayer

I am attempting to add 4 UIView subviews to a UIImageView. These subviews are to act as nodes where a user can tap them and connect to other nodes. For example, they should look
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0mZA.png). Instead, they are looking [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdNuO.png).

My code for calculating the node positions is as follows:

```
func initializeConnectionNodes() {
        let imageCenter = self.imageView.center
        let xOffset = self.imageView.bounds.width/2 //distance from origin x-wise
        let yOffset = self.imageView.bounds.height/2 //distance from origin y-wise
        self.leftConnectionNode = ConnectionNodeView(connectionPoint: CGPoint(x: imageCenter.x - xOffset, y: imageCenter.y))
        self.rightConnectionNode = ConnectionNodeView(connectionPoint: CGPoint(x: imageCenter.x + xOffset, y: imageCenter.y))
        self.topConnectionNode = ConnectionNodeView(connectionPoint: CGPoint(x: imageCenter.x, y: imageCenter.y + yOffset))
        self.bottomConnectionNode = ConnectionNodeView(connectionPoint: CGPoint(x: imageCenter.x, y: imageCenter.y - yOffset))

        self.imageView.addSubview(self.leftConnectionNode!)
        self.imageView.addSubview(self.rightConnectionNode!)
        self.imageView.addSubview(self.topConnectionNode!)
        self.imageView.addSubview(self.bottomConnectionNode!)
}
```

My code for initialization of the UIView class is as follows:

```
class ConnectionNodeView: UIView {

var connectionPoint: CGPoint
fileprivate var circleLayer: CAShapeLayer?

init(connectionPoint: CGPoint) {
    self.connectionPoint = connectionPoint
    super.init(frame: CGRect(x: connectionPoint.x, y: connectionPoint.y, width: 0, height: 0))

    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: connectionPoint, radius: CGFloat(8), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(Double.pi * 2), clockwise: true)
    self.circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    self.circleLayer?.path = circlePath.cgPath
    self.circleLayer?.fillColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
    self.circleLayer?.strokeColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
    self.circleLayer?.lineWidth = 3.0
    self.layer.addSublayer(circleLayer!)
}
```

It is interesting to note that if I just add the CAShapeLayer as a sublayer to my UIImageView, it looks like it should. However, I need to implement it as a UIView so that I can use gesture recognizers easily. I found a dirty way of fixing it by dividing the coordinates by 100 in the initializer like this:

```
super.init(frame: CGRect(x: connectionPoint.x/100, y: connectionPoint.y/100, width: 0, height: 0))
```

However, I would rather do it correctly. What am I missing here? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re adding the views to your image view, but the `imageCenter` point is given according to the **superview** of the image view.

Replace the beginning of the `initializeConnectionNodes` function with the following:

```
let xCenter = imageView.bounds.width / 2
let yCenter = imageView.bounds.height / 2

leftConnectionNode = ConnectionNodeView(connectionPoint: CGPoint(x: 0, y: yCenter))
rightConnectionNode = ConnectionNodeView(connectionPoint: CGPoint(x: imageView.bounds.width, y: yCenter))
topConnectionNode = ConnectionNodeView(connectionPoint: CGPoint(x: xCenter, y: 0))
bottomConnectionNode = ConnectionNodeView(connectionPoint: CGPoint(x: xCenter, y: imageView.bounds.height))
```

Also, you should replace the arc center of `circlePath` in your `ConnectionNodeView` subclass with `CGPoint.zero`, since it works with the coordinate system of the node view itself:

```
let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: .zero, radius: 8, startAngle: 0, endAngle:CGFloat(Double.pi * 2), clockwise: true)
```